# How to unpivot pandas dataframe to create datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, melt

I have a pivoted pandas dataframe that looks like the one below.
I need to unpivot it into a dataframe indexed by datetime, and the variables (columns) reduced to only one of each.

I tried using melt but I am struggling to reshape it because of the hour row.
What would be the best option to reshape such a dataframe?

The dataframe I have

```
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   nan    | var1 | var1 | var2 | var2 | var3 |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Hour     |    2 |    3 |    0 |    2 |    0 |
| 1/1/2019 |  0.8 |  0.4 |  0.6 |  0.9 |  0.7 |
| 1/2/2019 |  0.2 |  0.2 |  0.7 |  0.3 |  0.1 |
| 1/3/2019 |  0.1 |  0.0 |  0.3 |  0.4 |  1.0 |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

The dataframe I need to get

```
+---------------+------+------+------+
|   Datetime    | var1 | var2 | var3 |
+---------------+------+------+------+
| 1/1/2019 0:00 | NaN  | 0.6  | 0.7  |
| 1/1/2019 1:00 | NaN  | NaN  | NaN  |
| 1/1/2019 2:00 | 0.8  | 0.9  | NaN  |
| 1/1/2019 3:00 | 0.4  | NaN  | NaN  |
| 1/2/2019 0:00 | NaN  | 0.7  | 0.1  |
| 1/2/2019 1:00 | NaN  | NaN  | NaN  |
| 1/2/2019 2:00 | 0.2  | 0.3  | NaN  |
| 1/2/2019 3:00 | 0.2  | NaN  | NaN  |
| 1/3/2019 0:00 | NaN  | 0.3  | 1.0  |
| 1/3/2019 1:00 | NaN  | NaN  | NaN  |
| 1/3/2019 2:00 | 0.1  | 0.4  | NaN  |
| 1/3/2019 3:00 | 0.0  | NaN  | NaN  |
+---------------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really shitty answer that is unidiomatic pandas, but gets the job done given the data you presented in the format you presented in.  If you have massive amount of data I highly recommend you find a more optimized way.

```
dff = df.copy()

mn, mx = df.loc['Hour'].agg([min, max]).astype(int)

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(mx-mn+1)]
df = df.loc[df.index != 'Hour']
df = df.assign(time=list(range(mn,mx+1))*(mx-mn))
df = df.set_index('time', append=True).iloc[:,:0]

for i,v in enumerate(dff.columns):
    d = dff.iloc[:, i].to_frame()
    hour = d.at['Hour', v]
    for idx, row in d.iloc[1:].iterrows():
        df.loc[(idx, hour), v] = row[v]

df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'date'})
df['datetime'] = df[['date', 'time']].apply(lambda x: f"{x['date']} {x['time']}:00", axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns=['date', 'time']).set_index('datetime').reset_index()

print(df)

         datetime   v1   v2   v3
0   1/1/2019 0:00  NaN  0.6  0.7
1   1/1/2019 1:00  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   1/1/2019 2:00  0.8  0.9  NaN
3   1/1/2019 3:00  0.4  NaN  NaN     
4   1/2/2019 0:00  NaN  0.7  0.1
5   1/2/2019 1:00  NaN  NaN  NaN
6   1/2/2019 2:00  0.2  0.3  NaN
7   1/2/2019 3:00  0.2  NaN  NaN
8   1/3/2019 0:00  NaN  0.3  1.0
9   1/3/2019 1:00  NaN  NaN  NaN
10  1/3/2019 2:00  0.1  0.4  NaN
11  1/3/2019 3:00  0.0  NaN  NaN
```